# Having trouble with mime type detection in php

Tags: file-upload, mime-types

I have a form that should accept the upload of CVS files.
So i protected it with the following:

```
if (!in_array($mimeType, array("text/csv"))) throw new TMSException("Error");
```

All my tests went well on my dev environment, but now I found out that, on windows client, for the same exact file, I get a different mime type.

This is what I get when connecting on my Ubuntu PC:

```
/var/www/ct/preinvoice.php:203:
array (size=1)
  'tariffLines' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'C&T - Labatut.csv' (length=17)
      'type' => string 'text/csv' (length=8)
      'tmp_name' => string '/tmp/php2vIcaE' (length=14)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 3812
```

And this is what I get when trying to upload the same file from a windows machine:

```
/var/www/ct/preinvoice.php:203:
array (size=1)
  'tariffLines' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'C&T - Labatut.csv' (length=17)
      'type' => string 'application/vnd.ms-excel' (length=24)
      'tmp_name' => string '/tmp/phpPaMvN3' (length=14)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 3812
```

Any ideia of why PHP detects a different mime type for the same file? And how I can solve this?

Comment: The mime type might not be 'text/csv' some systems read/save them differently. (Internet Explorers treats .csv files as application/vnd.ms-excel)

Comment: Hi!
I'm testing the upload with the same file, and with chrome in both environment, and in windows, $_FILES["file"]["type"] is 'application/vnd.ms-excel';

I guess I'll have to use a different approach

Comment: The client sets the MIME type. You have no control over it.

Comment: It can be the same file, it is just treated differently by Windows. Most browsers are pulling the mime type from the registry here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch this issue by doing the following:

```
$mimetypes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel','text/csv');
if(in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$mimetypes)){
  // do something
} else {
  die("MIME type is not allowed");
}
```

Comment: Though you anwer is correct, I don't want to accept excel files. I used 
    `$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES["tariffLines"]["tmp_name"]);
    finfo_close($finfo);`
to force the system to check for the mime type. This way, everytime I get a "text/plain" mime type